# making changes to an asp.net site without reuploading the whole thing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm building a site and for the moment, when I want to put it on the web server, I to go Build > Publish WebSite to a local directory and then on the FTP, I delete the whole existing content and then upload the new fresh content that's on my local directory. In the Publish Web Site popup, I see that there's an option for "Allow this precompiled site to be updatable".

If I make changes to some files in my AppCode directory, how do I update the server WITHOUT essentially shutting it down?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're using a precompiled site or a web application, all "regular" websites are updateable -- App_Code as well as content.

Precompiled sites can be made to be updateable, but I believe only for web pages, not for code files.

If you have a busy site with lots of updates it's possible that updates can break things until they're complete. You can work around that by creating a file called app_offline.htm at the top level of your site. That will effectively take your site offline as long as it's there. The contents of the file are sent to users instead of your active content, such as *.aspx files. When the update is complete, then remove the file.

Comment: Thanks Rick; read and loved your book:) If I FTP an app_offline.htm file, will that also block my static pages? I have an site that has some static HTML pages that rely on masterpages; if I want the static HTML front-end pages to still be available and close the logged-in section of the site, what's the best way to do it?

Comment: Glad to hear you enjoyed the book. app_offline.htm only blocks dynamic content; static HTML, images, JavaScript, etc, should still be available.

Comment: ok, what if I'm using a masterpage to generate the static? Are they still considered "static"?

Comment: The master pages will stop working. If the "static" files are generated on demand, then they're really dynamic, and will stop working when app_offline.htm appears (it's the processing path that matters, not the file's extension). If they're processed by IIS without hitting the ASP.NET runtime, then they're static and will continue to work. It's easy to test in your dev environment, just use IIS or IIS Express, rather than Cassini.

Comment: ok, thanks for the advice; I'll think of a to take the site "offline" so that my content pages continue working while I update the logged-in section.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb840038

All that you need is a Synchronization between VS and server.

Comment: Ok, these frameworks look interesting. Is there anyway to do this straight out of VS?

Comment: I don't think so. The best way is like RickNZ wrote, I do the same.